# ILMerge StackOverflow Exception

Tags: stack-overflow, ilmerge

I am trying to run ILMerge to combine my own assembly with three third party assemblies.

```
var ilmerge = new ILMerging.ILMerge();

ilmerge.SetInputAssemblies(new string[] {
    @"C:\dev\MyAssembly.dll",
    @"C:\dev\Nest.dll",
    @"C:\dev\Elasticsearch.Net.dll",
    @"C:\dev\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
});

ilmerge.OutputFile = @"C:\dev\MyAssembly.Merged.dll";

ilmerge.Merge();
```

And am getting the following exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ILMerge.exe
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/09/using-ilmerge-with-net-40-andor-rx.html) by Stephen Cleary gives the answer. The `.SetTargetPlatform(string, string);` method should be used as below.

```
var ilmerge = new ILMerging.ILMerge();

ilmerge.SetInputAssemblies(new string[] {
    @"C:\dev\MyAssembly.dll",
    @"C:\dev\Nest.dll",
    @"C:\dev\Elasticsearch.Net.dll",
    @"C:\dev\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
});

ilmerge.SetTargetPlatform("v4", @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319");

ilmerge.OutputFile = @"C:\dev\MyAssembly.Merged.dll";

ilmerge.Merge();
```

Comment: If you're running ILMerge.exe from the command line, this can also be done by using /targetversion:version,platformdirectory